# iOS Remote Notification not received unless running from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm using Firebase to send silent remote notification to an iOS app. When running the app from Xcode it works fine both when the app is in foreground and background. It's fast and it works.

But, if I stop running from Xcode and start app from my device the notifications is not received regardless if the app is in the foreground or background. Sometimes I get the notification after 15+ minutes, but not always. Sometimes the notification appears if I open the app.

My notification have **priority** 10, **content_available** true and **data**. It does not have a title/body since I only wan't to trigger a network request and the show a local notification to the user based on the result of the network request.

Any ideas why this is?

Edit: If I include a title/body in the payload, the notification is delivered directly even without running from Xcode, but it doesn't seem to allow me to run code in the background until the notification is activated (`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:userinfo` is not run).

Comment: .entitlement file is physically present in your project?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't seem to be connected to any targets and it has a aps environment of development. Is this normal?

Comment: Your Edit made it confusing. Is it now **receiving** if you disconnect from Xcode?

Comment: If I include Notification content as a regular push notification it is received right away, but if I only include data och content_available is does not unless running from Xcode.

Comment: This makes me sure that I my configuration on Developer portal and Firebase correctly.

Comment: This post discusses a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223405/ios-empty-firebase-push-notification-doesnt-show-up