# iOS empty Firebase Push notification doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm having a weird problem with Firebase notification on iOS. It works perfectly but the only problem is if I keep the 'body' parameter on the server empty it does play notification  sound on the app but doesn't show anything. Same thing displays notification on Android. Is it some kind of Apple security that I'm running into? if I only add an empty space " " in 'body' it would show up but nothing without it. If any body could suggest me anything please.
my server side code

```
 $msg = array
          (
        'title'     => '',
        'body'  => ' ',
        'click_action' => '.InstagramLoader',
      'icon'    => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
         'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
          );

        $data = array(
'text' => $title,
'img_url' => $img_url
);


    $fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $registrationIds,
                'notification'  => $msg,
                'data' => $data
            );




    $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
#Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: This post discusses a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214234/ios-remote-notification-not-received-unless-running-from-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's an iOS thing, why show an empty push notification right? You could use isNaN() in your server side code and check for an empty body and set it to a default value.